# Is there a difference in VOID and void, in c++?

Tags: c++, void, difference

I've read some other questions similar to this, but I still don't know if
there is a difference in terms of usage between "VOID" and "void".

I feel uncomfortable using VOID without knowing the exact difference with void.

Any comforting advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It depends on how `VOID` is defined. It's not part of the standard language or standard library. Sounds like a Windows thing.

Comment: `VOID` is not a standard thing. It must be a typedef coming from somewhere. Check the documentation of where you got it. Perhaps `<windows.h>`?

Comment: I went to the definition which displayed "#define VOID void" in the "winnt.h". Does this mean that VOID is exactly same as void?

Comment: @CodeDoctorJL - No, it means that the preprocessor will replace all occurrences of `VOID` in your code with `void` before the compilation step.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`void` is a keyword reserved by the language, but `VOID` is not. It is defined in "winnt.h" as follows:

```
#ifndef VOID
#define VOID void
```

So they are essentially the same and can be used interchangeably. Sometimes one is used in place of the other for conventions' sake, but it doesn't matter which one you use. The preprocessor will end up replacing `VOID` with `void` in your code anyway because that is what `#define` does.

Actually a lot of keywords are "typedefed" in Windows to their capital. I think it is just to ensure compatibility between 8-bit, 16-bit and 32-bit Windows. Why they did that with `void` though... That's just Windows being weird. (As far as I know)

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that `void` is part of the language and `VOID` is not.  If you look at the output of the preprocessor for one of your source files containing `VOID`, you should be able to find a line that contains a line something like:

```
typedef void VOID;
```

Which should make you feel better.

Edit:  I see from your comment above that there's a `#define VOID void` line.  In that case, you know they're the same, but you likely won't see any `VOID` in the preprocessor output.  What you *will* see, is that everywhere in your code that you used `VOID`, the preprocessed output will have `void` instead.

Comment: Which means, that you should be using `void`, not `VOID`, because the first is the standard while the later is not.